# How to dynamically build a data structure in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any plugin that allow to dynamically build following data structure in plain JavaScript object or JSON?

This is the structure I would like to implement:

Check my plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/1eWjXLPumuOMhv8BjaNw?p=preview)

```
{
    "name": "Select0",
    "id": "select0",
    "values": [
        "Option1",
        "Option2"
    ],
    "dependent": {
        "name": "Select1",
        "id": "select1",
        "values": {
            "Option1": [
                "Option11",
                "Option12"
            ],
            "Option2": [
                "Option21",
                "Option22"
            ]
        },
        "dependent": {
            "name": "Select2",
            "id": "select2",
            "values": {
                "Option1": {
                    "Option11": [
                        "Option111",
                        "Option112"
                    ],
                    "Option12": [
                        "Option121",
                        "Option122"
                    ]
                },
                "Option2": {
                    "Option21": [
                        "Option211",
                        "Option212"
                    ],
                    "Option22": [
                        "Option221",
                        "Option222"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependent": []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just posted an object literal that is totally pure javascript and evaluates to the data structure that you want. What do you mean by "dynamically build"? From what?

Comment: User needs to input those values by using understable ui

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can set values on properties on an object and then print it as a JSON.

```
var obj = {};
object.name = "Select0";
// Set more properities.
// Stringify object to JSON format looking as the one in the question.
var json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
// Verify by printing on the screen.
console.log(json);
```